# How to make the data of the sub-component display the initial state in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

When I have a parent-child component, the child component has something like data {name:'defauleName' }, and a text box is bound to the name attribute. Is there a native solution for Vuejs to automatically restore the name to'defauleName' when the child component changes from hidden to displayed state. It looks like a new ChildComponent is initialized every time a child component is displayed. Or can be understood as the opposite keep-alive

Parent.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
       <Child v-if="show" />
       <el-checkbox v-model="show">展示/隐藏子组件</el-checkbox>
    </div>
</template>
<scirpt>
export default {
   data(){
       return {
         show: true
       }
   }
}
</script>
```

Child.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
       <el-input v-model="form.text" />
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            form: {
                text: 'defaultText'
            }
        }
    }
 </script>
```

When Child is displayed for the first time, enter "newText" in the text box, close Child, and then open Child again, you will see "newText". I know you can reset the Child data before closing the Child or opening the Child, but is there an option to display the initial value of the Child every time it is displayed?

Comment: Can you add minimal code that you tried, instead of just posting the question.

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason, because my Child component is el-dialog, it uses v-show internally